# Zonal identification and statistics in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.3

I hate to ask a poor question like this one, but I have literally spent 3 hours in a task that would have taken a few minutes in MATLAB or R.

**Input** : a floating point raster map, ranging from 0 to 2 (say).

**Desired output**: a polygon shapefile, where each polygon defines areas where `inputRaster > 1`. The shapefile table should hold some statistics (say mean and standard deviation) about each polygon.

I have tried and chained dozens of tools, tried creating a model, but now I am back here asking for help. Mostly because I think it should not be that difficult, and so probably I am missing something.

Comment: Do you have the Spatial Analyst extension?

Comment: @JWallace yes sir. I have tried zonal statistics. The problems are a) getting “zones” is *soooo* tedious (AFAIK you have to create a mask first with Map Algebra, then get polygons from there, then use the object id to distinguish zones, ....), b) the output is a floating point raster, so you can’t even convert it back to polygons... This really has driven me mad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right - this isn't the most intuitive workflow in Arc. Here is one way to accomplish this:

1. Reclassify your raster to however many meaningful values you need.  If you only need values >1, then simply do a 2-class reclassify (>1; <=1).
2. Perform Raster to Polygon conversion on your reclassed raster.
3. Run Zonal Statistics using your new polygon data as the feature zone data, and your **Original**, unclassified raster as the value raster.
4. Your output (I suggest running Zonal Statistics as Table) will include summary data for all raster areas coincident with your >1 polygon areas.

Note that if you simply use your >1 polygons as the value zone, then your output statistics will be generated for the >1 area as a whole.  If you need to have summary statistics for each individual polygon that represents a >1 area, you will need to use/create a unique ID (may be able to use the FID) for each >1 polygon, and use that ID as the value zone field when running Zonal Statistics. In this instance, I would suggest deleting all polygons that you are not interested in (e.g. <=1), so that you have a somewhat more manageable zonal output table that you can link back to your polygon data.  Let me know if I misunderstood your desired output.

Comment: I’ll do like so. I didn't think of getting a table and then joining it back. Thank you for saying it’s not so intuitive :-)